python scrap website data provides null values
I'm tring to scrap the MLB BOX scores and Play by play information.

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sportsnet.ca/baseball/mlb/games/2618275/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Capture values from linescore__container class
linescore_container = soup.find("div", class_="linescore__container")
teams = [team.text.strip() for team in linescore_container.find_all("div", class_="team__name")]
scores = [score.text.strip() for score in linescore_container.find_all("div", class_="team__score")]

# Capture values from AllIningsPBP__Wrapper class
innings_wrapper = soup.find("div", class_="AllIningsPBP__Wrapper")
innings = [inning.text.strip() for inning in innings_wrapper.find_all("div", class_="AllIningsPBP__Inning")]
totals = [total.text.strip() for total in innings_wrapper.find_all("div", class_="AllIningsPBP__Total")]

# Print captured values
print("title:", soup.title.text)
print("teams:", teams)
print("scores:", scores)
print("innings:", innings)
print("totals:", totals)


//////////////////////////////////
Output
Output is blank and it does  not capture the AllIningsPBP__Wrapper values 
title: Sportsnet.ca
teams: []
scores: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
innings: []
totals: []
pitchers: []

////////////////
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mlb.com/gameday/orioles-vs-pirates/2024/04/07/745523/final/wrap"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find and extract the desired data
    title = soup.title.text.strip()
    teams = [team.text.strip() for team in soup.find_all("span", class_="team-name")]
    scores = [score.text.strip() for score in soup.find_all("span", class_="team-score")]

    innings_table = soup.find("table", class_="linescore-table")
    if innings_table:
        innings_data = []
        for row in innings_table.find_all("tr"):
            inning_cells = row.find_all("td")
            inning_values = [cell.text.strip() for cell in inning_cells]
            innings_data.append(inning_values)

    innings_description = []
    innings_description_wrapper = soup.find("div", class_="AllInningsPBP__Wrapper")
    if innings_description_wrapper:
        innings_description = [item.text.strip() for item in innings_description_wrapper.find_all("div", class_="AllIningsPBP__Inning")]

    # Print the extracted data
    print("Title:", title)
    print("Teams:", teams)
    print("Scores:", scores)
    print("Innings Data:", innings_data)
    print("Innings Description:", innings_description)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data from the URL.")

/////////////////
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.thebaseballcube.com/content/box/CHN202303300~r/"

# Add a header to mimic a real browser request
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36"
}

# Send a GET request to the URL with headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # Extract title
    title = soup.title.text.strip()

    # Extract teams
    teams = [team.text.strip() for team in soup.find_all("span", class_="bold")]

    # Extract scores
    scores = [score.text.strip() for score in soup.find_all("td", class_="bold")]

    # Extract innings data
    innings_data = []
    for inning in soup.find_all("tr", class_="box_line_score"):
        inning_text = " ".join(cell.text.strip() for cell in inning.find_all("td"))
        innings_data.append(inning_text)

    # Print the extracted data
    print("Title:", title)
    print("Teams:", teams)
    print("Scores:", scores)
    print("Innings Data:", innings_data)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data from the URL.")

////////////////////////
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://plaintextsports.com/mlb/2024-04-07/bal-pit#play-by-play"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find the play-by-play section
    play_by_play_section = soup.find("section", id="play-by-play")

    if play_by_play_section:
        # Extract the play-by-play data
        play_by_play = play_by_play_section.text.strip()

        # Print the play-by-play data
        print("Play-by-Play:")
        print(play_by_play)
    else:
        print("Play-by-play section not found on the page.")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data from the URL.")

///////////////////
Does these Websites have some kind of security measures?
Can we bypass them or do we need to manually scrap the data?
I have tried multiple sites.
Expecting to Scrap the Box Scores and all the play by Play Info
Diamondbacks
4-6
Final
2 - 5
Atlanta
Braves
6-2

Play-by-Play   Box Score

      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9    T  H  E
------------------------------------------
ARI   0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0    2  5  1
ATL   0  2  0  1  0  0  0  2  x    5  7  0
  
W: Chris Sale (1-0)
L: Ryne Nelson (0-2)
S: Pierce Johnson (1)
Game Time: 2:30
 
Play-by-play:              Only Scoring Plays
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
 
1st Inning:                              Hide
 
T1 
 
Ketel Marte strikes out swinging.
 
  0-0
 
T1 
 
Corbin Carroll grounds out to first baseman Matt Olson.
 
  0-0
 
T1 
 
Lourdes Gurriel Jr. lines out sharply to left fielder Jarred Kelenic.
 
  0-0
 
Middle 1st
 
B1 
 
Ronald Acuña Jr. pops out to first baseman Christian Walker.
 
  0-0
 
B1 
 
Ozzie Albies grounds out to first baseman Christian Walker.
 
  0-0
 
B1 
 
Austin Riley pops out to first baseman Christian Walker in foul territory.
 
  0-0
 
2nd Inning:                              Hide
 
T2 
 
Christian Walker strikes out swinging.
 
  0-0


No clue what you're wanting as an outcome - you have 5 snippets of code, no description of the expected output versus what you are actually getting. What's the issue???
But, few suggestions though from what I am seeing.

If it's a <table> tags in the html, use pandas' to parse the table .read_html(). It returns a list of dataframes/tables. You can use the index to pull out the one you want, or print them all out in a loop.

Code:
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.thebaseballcube.com/content/box/CHN202303300~r/"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)

Output:
                  0   1   ...      20                                          21
0               team   1  ...  mlb rk                                  2023 links
1  Milwaukee Brewers   0  ...       4  statistics | roster | game log | NEXT Game
2       Chicago Cubs   0  ...      25  statistics | roster | game log | NEXT Game

[3 rows x 22 columns]
        0                  1       2       3   ...    17     18    19    20
0       ln             player     pos     age  ...   avg    ops  s gm  c gm
1        1   Christian Yelich      lf  31.115  ...  .000   .500     1  1251
2        2       Jesse Winker      dh  29.225  ...  .000   .000     1   550
3        3       Willy Adames      ss  27.209  ...  .333   .833     1   574
4        4       Rowdy Tellez      1b  28.014  ...  .000   .250     1   430
5        5  William Contreras       c  25.096  ...  .250   .500     1   155
6        6         Luis Urias      3b  25.300  ...  .000   .000     1   397
7        7       Cal Mitchell      cf  24.022  ...  .000   .000     1    32
8        8     Brian Anderson      rf  29.315  ...  .500  1.167     1   532
9        9       Brice Turang      2b  23.129  ...  .333   .667     1     1
10  Totals             Totals  Totals  Totals  ...     -      -     9  3922

[11 rows x 21 columns]
        0                  1       2       3   ...    17     18    19    20
0       ln             player     pos     age  ...   avg    ops  s gm  c gm
1        1       Nico Hoerner      2b  25.321  ...  .250   .500     1   250
2        2     Dansby Swanson      ss  29.047  ...  .750  1.500     1   829
3        3           Ian Happ      lf  28.230  ...  .500  1.250     1   679
4        4     Cody Bellinger      cf  27.260  ...  .000   .250     1   746
5        5       Trey Mancini      dh  31.011  ...  .333   .833     1   752
6        6          Yan Gomes       c  35.254  ...  .000   .000     1   974
7        7        Eric Hosmer      1b  33.157  ...  .000   .000     1  1660
8        8     Patrick Wisdom      3b  31.215  ...  .000   .250     1   285
9        9  Miles Mastrobuoni      rf  27.150  ...  .000   .000     1    10
10  Totals             Totals  Totals  Totals  ...     -      -     9  6185

[11 rows x 21 columns]
       0                      1       2    3  4   ...    16    17    18    19    20
0     seq                 player     age   ip  h  ...  inpl   era  whip  s gm  c gm
1       1  Corbin Burnes (L 0-1)  28.159  5.0  4  ...    16  7.20  1.40     1   136
2       2       Peter Strzelecki  28.157  1.0  0  ...     3  0.00  0.00     1    31
3       3            Gus Varland  26.143  1.0  2  ...     4  0.00  3.00     1     1
4       4            Javy Guerra  27.182  1.0  0  ...     2  0.00  0.00     1    45
5  Totals                 Totals  Totals  8.0  6  ...    25     -     -   NaN   NaN

[6 rows x 21 columns]
       0                       1       2    3  4   ...    16    17    18    19    20
0     seq                  player     age   ip  h  ...  inpl   era  whip  s gm  c gm
1       1  Marcus Stroman (W 1-0)  31.333  6.0  3  ...    12  0.00  1.00     1   205
2       2         Keegan Thompson  28.017  1.0  0  ...     2  0.00  1.00     1    62
3       3          Brad Boxberger  34.306  1.0  0  ...     1  0.00  1.00     1   485
4       4          Michael Fulmer  30.014  1.0  1  ...     2  0.00  1.00     1   205
5  Totals                  Totals  Totals  9.0  4  ...    17     -     -   NaN   NaN

[6 rows x 21 columns]


Don't bother with getting the html and parsing with beautifulsoup when the data comes from an API in a nice json format. It's more robust to get it from the API and more often than not, you'll get far more data than what is shown in the html. It's also easier to parse.

Code:
import pandas as pd
import requests

gameID = 2616911
url = f'https://mobile-statsv2.sportsnet.ca/livetracker?league=mlb&id={gameID}'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()


pbp = jsonData['data']['game']['innings']
pbp_df = pd.json_normalize(pbp,
                           record_path='plays')

Output:
    event_id  event_code                                   description is_out
0         16          65                         Schwarber struck out.      1
1         31          51  Turner flied out to center fielder Thompson.      2
2         16          65                          Realmuto struck out.      3
3          4         122     Fairchild hit an infield single to third.       
4         16          65                             Steer struck out.      1
..       ...         ...                                           ...    ...
73         2          42                                                     
74         1          98                             Hoffman pitching.       
75        16          65                          Thompson struck out.      1
76        34          72  Fairchild lined out to center fielder Rojas.      2
77        16          65                             Steer struck out.      3


Here's an example where you will want to use beautifulsoup to parse the data. The solution below from Ravi will work, but always use Selenium as a last resort - selenium is overkill when you can get the html response from a simple request.

Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://plaintextsports.com/mlb/2024-04-07/bal-pit#play-by-play'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
pbp_elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'play-by-play'})

for each in pbp_elements:
    print(each.text)

Output:
T1  
Gunnar Henderson strikes out swinging. 
  0-0 
T1  
Adley Rutschman lines out to right fielder Connor Joe. 
  0-0 
T1  
Ryan Mountcastle doubles (4) on a sharp line drive to right fielder Connor Joe. 
  0-0 
T1  
Anthony Santander lines out to center fielder Jack Suwinski. 
  0-0
 
B1  
Oneil Cruz grounds out, second baseman Jorge Mateo to first baseman Ryan Mountcastle. 
  0-0 
B1  
Bryan Reynolds strikes out swinging, catcher James McCann to first baseman Ryan Mountcastle. 
  0-0 
B1  
Ke'Bryan Hayes singles on a line drive to right fielder Anthony Santander. 
  0-0 
B1  
Jack Suwinski pops out to third baseman Jordan Westburg in foul territory. 

...


Hello, Thanks for the response. looking to scrap the scores: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']  and Play by Play info from https://plaintextsports.com/mlb/2024-04-07/bal-pit#play-by-play

the code above doesnt work for you?

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # To run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

# Set up the Chrome driver
service = Service("path/to/your/chromedriver")  # Replace with the path to your 
 chromedriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

 # URL of the webpage to scrape
 url = "https://plaintextsports.com/mlb/2024-04-07/bal-pit#play-by-play"

 # Load the webpage
 driver.get(url)

# Wait for the play-by-play section to load
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the waiting time as needed

# Find the play-by-play section
play_by_play_section = driver.find_element(By.ID, "play-by-play")

# Get the play-by-play text
play_by_play_text = play_by_play_section.text

# Print the play-by-play data
print("Play-by-play:")
print(play_by_play_text)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

Hope this helps
